# Ledger Nano S ethereum question

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I am trying to send my ethereum on ledger wallet ethereum to bittrex. I've sent 8 times and it gets cancelled due to running out of gas. Unless I'm crazy there is no way to increase the amount of GAS, 21000. No idea what to do, should of just stuck with btc

Comment: what content do I need to fill in "contract data hex"?

Comment: A bit more specific about your context would be helpful. But my guess is you are after either web3.eth.contract.getData (for current web3 version, see https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods), or for the beta version of web3,  contract.method.encodedABI (see https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#encodeABI)

Comment: Please don't ask a question in an answer. Use comments for this or open a new question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20683)

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `ADVANCED MODE` at the bottom left of your ledger wallet Ethereum and change the `GAS PRICE`.